# It is supposed that

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

Could someone say if I understand the phrase "it is supposed that" right?

For example:

> It is supposed that tigers don't like swimming in water.

I understand this sentence like there's some random group of people or any random person on Earth who think/believe that tigers don't like swimming in water.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The idiomatic English expression is 'Tigers are not supposed to like swimming in water'. Your own expression is too definite . . . 'it is supposed'. And by stating the passive as you have done, the question arises - by whom ? But the idiomatic expression allows for the supposition being incorrect and also does not draw attention to any particular subject as the supposer. This is actually a very good question about the English way of expressing the passive. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're at least close to right.

The "is supposed" construction is in the present tense, passive voice, indefinite aspect and indicative mode.   The passive voice clause "it is supposed that tigers don't like swimming" can be cast in the active voice: "someone supposes that tigers don't like swimming".   In the passive voice, the subject represents a semantic *theme*.   In the active, the subject represents a semantic *agent*.

Even in the passive voice, the existence of some agent is implied.   There's nothing necessarily *random* about this agent.   The agent is simply *unspecified*.   An indeterminate number of unidentified people suppose that tigers don't like swimming.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!  Do you mean by "can be cast" something like "can be changed/modified"?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry.  I'm using the sense of *to cast* that means to express in a particular form.  The phrasing "can be transformed into an active voice representation" means the same thing.

Comment: Thank you again for your explanation :) I had no idea that "to cast" has this meaning, haha. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning behind this phrase is that most people hold this idea. So it isn't just any random group of people or a random person, it is instead the majority that thinks so. This is because the passive voice, which is used in this sentence, leaves out the subject. However the active voice of this sentence would be *People suppose that...*, so it refers to people in general. Similar constructions are for example *it is believed that* or *it is assumed that*, and they all state that people just share some opinion in general.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, tyler1! :) Does "most people hold this idea" mean "most people believe/think that this is true"?